# Не сериализуется JSON строка

Tags: python, json, django

Храню я в django следующее:

```
values = models.TextField(default='[]')  # Значения поля
```

При операции преобразования в список вылетает ошибка, что, мол, строка входная не может быть преобразована в json объект:

```
self.values = json.JSONDecoder().decode(self.values)
```

из-за того что, например, строка:

```
'[\\'22'\\']'
```

содержит экранирующие символы, когда я поднимаю поле из БД. Как это обойти? replace не поможет.

Comment: Как вы данные туда сохраняете?

Comment: self.fld_instance.values = str(self.values)
self.fld_instance.save()

похоже нужен json.dumps() ?

Comment: с json.dumps все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj = json.JSONDecoder().decode(json_text)` идентичен `obj = json.loads(json_text)`.

В обратную сторону:

```
json_text = json.dumps(obj)
```

`obj` и `json_text` принципиально различны. Не стоит использовать одно и то же имя до и после сериализации как json текст. Это может внести путаницу.